# ModelForm clean_xxxx() works for CharField, not for URLField. Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

How can I remove whitespace, prior to validation of a URLField?

Using "clean_[fieldname]()" would seem to be the documented way from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/ , but it does not work for the URLField.  I've reduced it to a basic test case which can be run in the django shell:

```
class XXXTestModel(models.Model):
    url  = models.URLField('URL',null=True,blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
class XXXTestForm(ModelForm):
    def clean_url(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['url'].strip()
    def clean_name(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['name'].strip() 
    class Meta:
        model = XXXTestModel
        fields = (
             'url',
        )
```

Tested from the Django shell with:

```
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 5, 1, 'final', 0)
>>> from xxx import XXXTestForm,XXXTestModel
>>> data = dict(url=' http://www.example.com/ ',name=' example ')
>>> f=XXXTestForm(data)
>>> f.is_valid();f.errors
False
{'url': [u'Enter a valid URL.']}
>>> f.cleaned_data
{'name': example'}
```

There are a number of close dupes of this question on stack overflow, but none of the answers guide toward a solution.

Comment: what do you get if you do `print self.cleaned_data['url']` in `def clean_url` ?

Comment: Nothing.  It appears never to be called.  (the above is a standalone example that can be pasted into the django shell).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is how the `django.forms.URLField` works.

`django.forms.Field.clean` is defined as:

```
def clean(self, value):
    """
    Validates the given value and returns its "cleaned" value as an
    appropriate Python object.

    Raises ValidationError for any errors.
    """
    value = self.to_python(value)
    self.validate(value)
    self.run_validators(value)
    return value
```

Note that `to_python` is performed before any validation. This is the issue here - `django.forms.URLField` can't understand the value you're giving it, so the value it produces fails the set of validators already defined as part of `django.forms.URLField` (namely, `django.core.validators.URLValidator`).

The reason it fails is django tries to "normalize" the URL. This includes things such as adding `"http://"` where needed. When given your example url, `" http://www.example.com "`, django uses `urlparse.urlsplit` to get it "parts" of the url. The leading space, however, messes it up and the entire value becomes part of the `path`. As such, django finds no `scheme`, and reconstitutes the URL as `"http:// http://www.example.com "`. This is then given to `django.core.validators.URLValidator`, which obviously fails.

To avoid this, we'll need to define our own `URLField` for our form

```
from django import forms

class StrippedURLField(forms.URLField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        return super(StrippedURLField, self).to_python(value and value.strip())
```

Using this ensures the process will all go as expected, and we wont need a `clean_url` method. (note: you should use `clean_*` where possible, but here it is not)

```
class XXXTestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    url = StrippedURLField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer, it was well worth the 50 points.